# Which is the best data structure and algorithm to be used in such a case

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Lets say out of bunch of fruits, each having a nutrition value and price tag attached, I need to select a group of fruits that can provide me the best total nutritional value with an expense limitation. For example, I need to select 5 different fruits and cannot max their total value of 50$ trying to make the best total nutritional value.

Comment: You might want to look at the knapsack problem. It's essentially the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Why would you not just compute the price per nutrition unit of each type of fruit, and then buy only the type of fruit with the lowest cost per nutrition unit?

Comment: The cost of each of the five fruit that have the best price per nutrition unit might be more than $50.

Comment: It's an integer linear program (ILP). GLPK will solve it for you.

Comment: @hatchet what you said is the greedy method which is well known that cannot solved this type of problem...consider following case:  You have total $10, with 3 food: $3 with 5 value, $7 with 13 value, $8 with 17 value. Using your method, one will choose $8 with 17 value, while choosing the other two gives a better result

Answer (score 1):

It is basically the famous [0-1 Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which can be solved by dynamic programming.

Here is a quote of what knapsack problem is:

> Given a set of items, each with a mass and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is less than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as large as possible.

That means in your case,

**the set of items is the fruit**

**value is the nutritional value**

**mass is the money**

Let m_i, v_i be the money and nutritional value of the i-th fruit

Define DP(i, w) be the state representing **the maximum total value possible choosing from the first i fruits, which total money used <= w**

Fill the base case i.e. DP(0, x) for all x

then do the dynamic programming with following transition

**DP(i,w) = DP(i-1, w) if m_i > w (You can think as one does not take the i-th fruit)**

**DP(i,w) = max(DP(i-1, w),  DP(i-1, w-m_i)+v_i) if m_i <= w (You can think as one either not choosing the i-th fruit or choose it, we take the option with greater value)**

Then your answer if **DP(n-1, 50) using 0-base**

Answer (score 0):

There is no data-structure for this problem. The algorithm you are looking for is 0-1 knapsack problem.See [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/)

The algorithm basically boils down to a recursion. for each fruit , you either take this fruit or leave it(0-1) . Going like this you will generate all the subsets of the fruits and take the best among that.

```
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
   // Base Case
   if (n == 0 || W == 0)
       return 0;

   // If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack capacity W, then
   // this item cannot be included in the optimal solution
   if (wt[n-1] > W)
       return knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1);

   // Return the maximum of two cases: (1) nth item included (2) not included
   else return max( val[n-1] + knapSack(W-wt[n-1], wt, val, n-1),
                knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1)
              );
}
```

You can apply DP afterwards(which I think you should try after you have completely grasped the idea of the main solution)